# Why doesn't cooltooltips work in this minimal example?

Tags: luatex

I'm try `cooltooltips` with this minimal example:

```
\documentclass{book}
%% test_coolToolTip_01
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{cooltooltips}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
    
\cooltooltip
[0 0 1]
{Example}
{This is an example of a cool tooltip. Pretty cool, eh?}
{http://www.ctan.org/}{Visit CTAN on the Web}
{This text}
\end{document}
```

But, it doesn't compile. Why? I don't understand why it doesn't compile, even though the example is extremely basic. The result should resemble what you see in [this post](//tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210603/insert-graphics-in-cool-tool-tips).

Comment: look at the date of the package: 2006/03/07 v1.0. It hasn't been adapted to luatex. You can try with the luatex85 package, but better ask the author for an update or try the pdfcomment package instead.

Comment: ok thank I understand  it's not maintained.  So by by cooltooltip

Answer (score 0):

Heeding [the suggestion from Ulrike](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/569286/#comment1434889_569286), [`cooltooltips`](//ctan.org/pkg/cooltooltips) hasn't been updated since 2006 and therefore is not compatible with Lua(La)TeX (and `polyglossia`). Better to move on to something more recent like [`pdfcomment`](//ctan.org/pkg/pdfcomment).